# Symfony version up-gradation from 3.4 to 4.3 using old folder structure and ERROR

Tags: symfony, symfony1, symfony4

I am trying to upgrade the Symfony version from 3.4 to 4.3 but the requirement is to keep the same folder structure as it was in 3.4 because of namespaces and other dependencies.

[image]

My Findings: 
1. Part of the setup is done. Need to configure for completion. 
2. In the new version, we need to inject other classes or service as like an Argument in method

But the problem is that while I install / update composer it always returns:

```
Script Symfony-cmd handling the auto-scripts event returned with error code 127
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

and Another Big problem is there in `app.php` or `app_dev.php`

Here is my JSON:

```
        {
        "name": "web",
        "license": "proprietary",
        "type": "project",
        "description": " Web",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "": "src/" },
        "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "symfony/symfony": "^3.4",
        "twig/twig": "^1.35",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "leaseweb/api-caller-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "^1.3",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.0.0",
        "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "^1.7",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.2",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^2.0",
        "misd/phone-number-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "snilius/twig-sort-by-field": "^0.1.5",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle": "1.0.*",
        "predis/predis":                        "^1.0",
        "snc/redis-bundle":                     "^2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6",
        "leafo/scssphp": "^0.6.7",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
        "eightpoints/guzzle-bundle": "dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.6",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "^1.6",
        "gpslab/geoip2": "^1.1",
        "ext-json" : "*",
        "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
    },
        "scripts": {
            "post-install-cmd": [
                "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget",
                "WebBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::createProfilePicDirectory"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
                "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget",
                "WebBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::createProfilePicDirectory"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "bin-dir": "bin"
        },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
        "extra": {
            "symfony-app-dir": "app",
            "symfony-web-dir": "web",
            "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
            "incenteev-parameters": {
                "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
            },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "1.2-dev"
        }
        }
    }
```

in APP.PHP

```
        <?php

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    /**
    * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
    */
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
    include_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

    // Enable APC for autoloading to improve performance.
    // You should change the ApcClassLoader first argument to a unique prefix
    // in order to prevent cache key conflicts with other applications
    // also using APC.
    /*
    $apcLoader = new Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader(sha1(__FILE__), $loader);
    $loader->unregister();
    $apcLoader->register(true);
    */

    $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
    $kernel->loadClassCache();
    //$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

    // When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
    //Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    Request::setTrustedHeaderName(Request::HEADER_FORWARDED, null);
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

ERRORS are getting :

ERROR 1. while composer install -> `Script Symfony-cmd handling the auto-scripts event returned with error code 127`

ERROR 2. `$response = $kernel->handle($request);` in `app.php`

Other API routes are working but for the handler, I am getting the error for `app.php` file.

Comment: did you followed to these instructions? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/UPGRADE-4.0.md, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/UPGRADE-4.1.md, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/UPGRADE-4.2.md, https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.3/UPGRADE-4.3.md. the point is that you likely *will* need to update your directory structure to something recognizable by `symfony4` and any issues with namespaces/dependencies should be resolvable. just name your problem

Comment: also take a look here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/setup/upgrade_major.html

Comment: @spirit I followed `symfony.com/doc/4.3/setup/upgrade_major.html` .. I will check the above links. But the problem is that I had keep the folder structure the same as 3.4 instead of 4.3

Comment: I'm telling that **maybe** you don't have to keep the structure and there is a simple solution to your case ;). What issues do you have when updating the structure?

Comment: No point in moving to 4.3.  Target the newly released 4.4 which (like 3.4) is also a Long Term Supported version.  The article on the [flex structure](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/setup/flex.html) might help.  It explains some of the steps required to update your composer.  This [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/9305) also discusses some of difficulties of using Symfony 4 without flex.

Comment: You mentioned namespaces as a reason for sticking with the 3.4 structure.  Your 3.4 app probably has an AppBundle and possibly a few other bundles under src.  Out of the box, 4.4 no longer requires an AppBundle however you can still have one.  So basically, with a few minor adjustments most if not all of your src code should work unchanged.  This assumes you have no depreciation notices in your 3.4 app.  You really should consider starting a new 4.4 app, load all your third party bundles and then try for a bit of copy/paste.